# Resizing NSWindow to fit child NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I have one main NSWindow which is empty, and 5 NSViews. The NSViews have different buttons and labels etc, and the window is empty. The first view displayed is a menu, linking to the other views and back. This works fine and the views switch well.

However if the NSWindow is a certain size, and the NSView is bigger, then it spills out of the NSWindow and gets cut off.

Is there any way such that when I do:

```
[_window setContentView: theNewView];
```

to also have `_window` resize to fit the new view? If this is possible, can this be done with an animation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`-[NSWindow setContentSize:]` does this (without animation). Give it the desired size of the content view and it will resize both content view and the window appropriately, e.g.

```
[_window setContentSize:theNewView.frame.size];
[_window setContentView:theNewView];
```

For animation, you need to compute window size manually using `frameRectForContentRect:` and then change window's frame with `animate:YES`:

```
[_window setContentView:theNewView];
NSRect viewScreenFrame = /*translate theNewView.frame to screen coordinates*/;
NSRect wndFrame = [_window frameRectForContentRect:viewScreenFrame];
[_window setFrame:wndFrame display:YES animate:YES];
```

Comment: works brilliantly. i looked everywhere and found nothing yet the answer is so simple. thanks!

Comment: is there any chance you can let me know how i translate the view to coordinates?

Comment: i figured it out - http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/162049-flipping-over-coordinate-conversion.html thanks again!