# NSView that resizes like UserDefaults, basically to fit content

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

I'd like a `NSView` to resize (larger and smaller) based on its currently viewed sub view. This is seen most often in UserDefaults but I would like it for a Modal Window.

I'm using a `NSTabView` inside the Window with 4 tabs. Each tab have quite different size requirements; and I'm hoping to avoid a lot of ugly empty space.

Is that a simple "Resize to fit content" button or something hand-baked.

I do see some similar questions, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177882/resizing-nswindow-to-fit-child-nsview) but none tackling `NSTabView`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a loop that loops through all the subviews and finds the frame with the largest CGRectGetMaxY(). Then i add a padding and resize the window to height. It works really well.